# Thevenin Equivalent of Common-Gate Amplifier

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog, fet, common-gate

[image]

[image]

I'm having some difficulty understanding how Razavi determined \$V_{\text{in, eq}}\$. My understanding was that the small-signal model allows us to model the PMOS device as a constant current source (\$g_mv_{gs}\$) with a resistor in parallel (\$r_o\$) and then he transformed that from a Norton Equivalent to Thevenin Equivalent?

**How is \$V_{\text{in, eq}}\$ derived?**

Comment: That makes two of us.  It's like a complementary source follower trying to achieve some delicate bias for very little gain at the drain.  Very unstable for low gain.

Comment: This performs worse than a simple common source with negative feedback & AC coupled. input

Answer (score 1):

That's not what is normally called a "common-gate" amplifier. That is a source follower feeding into a common gate amplifier.

Vin,eq is the output voltage of the source follower. Treat M1 as a source follower and calculate its output voltage.

Comment: oh, you're right! I missed that one of those was p-channel.

Comment: Also known as a complementary differential pair, as in the linear* range, the input term is (Vb - Vin + 2Vgs(th)). (*Constant current region; often, "saturation" for FETs, in contrast to the triode region, often, confusingly, called "linear".)